# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql

I'm facing this error while inserting some data to our database. My code for inserting data is below.The whole error message is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   '','nmnm','Female','01/06/2017','info@example.com','9999999999')' at
>   line 1' in /home/avfswallet/pancard.avfswallet.com/user.php:35 Stack
>   trace: #0 /home/avfswallet/pancard.avfswallet.com/user.php(35):
>   PDO->query('INSERT INTO use...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   /home/avfswallet/pancard.avfswallet.com/user.php on line 35

```
$category=$_POST['category'];
$req_type=$_POST['requestType'];
$lname=$_POST['last_name'];
$fname=$_POST['first_name'];
$mname=$_POST['middle_name'];
$gender=$_POST['iCheck'];
$birth=$_POST['dob'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
echo $category."<br/>";
echo $req_type."<br/>";
echo $lname."<br/>";
echo $fname."<br/>";
echo $mname."<br/>";
echo $gender."<br/>";
echo $birth."<br/>";
echo $email."<br/>";
echo $phone."<br/>";
$query="INSERT INTO users (app_category,user_title,last_name,first_name,middle_name,gender_type,dob,email_id,phone_no) VALUES('{$category}','{$req_type}','{$lname}',{$fname}','{$mname}','{$gender}','{$birth}','{$email}','{$phone}')";
```

Comment: This is a syntax error in query. Echo your `$query`.

Comment: I think there might be a chance for unsanitized values in the input. Don't ever directly insert values from $_POST .read about SQL injection

Comment: Even with fixing this typo, you would experience problems with inserting names like `O'Brian`, try it. Use prepared statements with placeholders!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using prepared statements with binds, but you mistake is a missing ' before fname...

```
$query="INSERT INTO users (app_category,user_title,last_name,first_name,middle_name,gender_type,dob,email_id,phone_no) VALUES('{$category}','{$req_type}','{$lname}','{$fname}','{$mname}','{$gender}','{$birth}','{$email}','{$phone}')";
```

Comment: what changes you have made?

Comment: As mentioned in answer - `,{$fname}',` changed to `,'{$fname}',`